# I am having an issue storing a character in a pointer to a structure.

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
String* substr(String* str, int start, int end)
{
   String* substr = new String;
   for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
   {
      substr = str->text[i];
   }   

   return substr;
}
```

//the problem is in the substr method. substr is supposed to store a part of a string     separated by a delimiter.

Comment: You need to copy the substring to the new String.

Comment: And give the new string a name which is different from the function, for heaven's sake!

Comment: There's really no need for pointers in a function like this.

Comment: the error im getting is 'cannot convert char to String*' I need to store the contents of str->text[i] in substr, but im not sure how to do this.

Comment: I assume you wrote the String class since String is not a c++ class?

Comment: yes i have a String struct that stores text in an array and the size of the array. We're using the struct to be able to separate the string by delimiters and then compare the separate tokens

Comment: Calling your function `substr` is a bit dicey too. In theory it's OK as the linker should distinguish between your `::substr` and `std::substr` but in practice I'm not so sure if you can rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `substr` is a pointer to the object of `String` struct, you should point to that object's array of chars. Something like this:

```
String* substr(String* str, int start, int end)
{
    String* substr = new String;
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        substr->text[i] = str->text[i];    // Now char = char
    }   

    return substr;
}
```

Depending on the way you handle that array of chars, you might face some further problems with the size of it.